# Regex for replacing certain words in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: regex, libreoffice

In LibreOffice Writer, I want to use regex to search for all words that start with the letter *c* and to replace them with themselves and another word.

For the first part, I use the following and all is fine.

```
\bc[a-z]+
```

Yet for the replace part, when I write

```
& text
```

it replaces `cat` with `& text` instead of `cat text`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers almost got it right. The find expression is correct:

```
\b(c[a-z]*)\b
```

I've used `*` in place of `+` in order to match `c` as a single word, and I've added a trailing `\b` to make the word limits more clear, but the original form is OK.

The replacement string should be:

```
$1 text
```

This does accord with Jim K's documentation link, but it is rather confusing in this area.

Specifically, `\1` can be used in the search expression, to repeat a string matched earlier in the expression, but `$1` must be used in the replacement string. The use in the search string means that `(a.b).*\1` will match `a` and `b` with a character between, followed by `a` and `b` with *the same* character between. This is not the same as `a.b.*a.b`, where the intervening characters may be different. The example in the documentation link is correct, but does nothing to explain where it will be useful.

As a final note, my version 5.1.4.2 of LibreOffice Writer refuses to make substitutions when the search string starts with `\b`, although it finds all the instances correctly; a trailing `\b` works as expected. This is a bug - OpenOffice 4.1.3 works correctly. The work-round is to use `([^a-z]\bc[a-z]*)\b` as the search string with the same replacement string: this works in all cases except when the first word of the document begins with `c`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have tested your regex on both LibreOffice Writer 5.2.5 and 5.3, and it still replaces `cat` with `$1 test`, although it correctly finds all the instances. The only situation in which it works is when the `c` word is at the beginning of the line. Since this regex is undoubtedly the correct one, it seems that we are dealing with a bug.

Comment: Since I've found a bug with the leading `\b`, maybe they still haven't got it right. Did you try my work-round?

Comment: My 5.1.4.2 was on Ubuntu 16.4.1. I just tested 5.2.5.1 on Win10 and got the same result - the strings are found, but not replaced, when I use a leading `\b`, while the work-round still does the job.

Comment: Thinking completely outside the box, I wonder if you have a Romanian keyboard and it's generating the alternative small dollar sign (U+FE69). Try copying and pasting the replacement string from my answer and see if that works properly. It's a wild guess, but it's the only explanation I can thing of. Note that the keyboard map for Writer is not necessarily the same as the normal system keyboard.

Comment: Yes, the work-around did the job in LibreOffice Writer 5.3.0.3. I don't know what went wrong in the first few tries (maybe I typed an extra blank space), but it now works precisely as you mentioned. It replaces the words correctly. I appreciate all of your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The "find" expression is missing parentheses to capture the word.

```
\b(c[a-z]+)
```

The "replace" expression is correct as is.

Documentation: https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions